# django frontend and backend seperation for security

Tags: django, security, web-application-firewall

I have written a web app in Django with usual Django project structure. At my company, they want to separate front end and backend on different servers. Frontend server will have internet access and backend will have a strong firewall and no net access.  What I understand from this concept is, they want to separate back-end (view.py) from Django project to shared folder (shared with the back-end server). Is it possible to separate view.py file to the different folder and then import it to project?

Also another question on the same topic. Does Django have good security or security ideas like this are required to protect against hacking? What measures should I take to ensure protecting my backend against hacking if I can't separate backend? (I have already implemented LDAP authentication, using CSRF tokens and all pages are protected by @login_required)

Answer (score 2):

What you can do is creating two projects, one for serving your "front end" with a disabled admin (simply remove the 'admin' in your project's urls.py) and another one for managing the django admin and only accessible from inside your company's network. 
Make them share the same database where the database server should only be accessible from within your company's network, as well. Be sure to only create the models only in one app, preferably in the front end app as you might want to have user input handled by django forms.
Register the "front-end" app models in the "back-end" project via the admin.py in the "back end" app. That should allow you accessing the data stored in the db.
When it comes to third party apps and plugins be sure to check their urls.py (and disable the admin in case), models.py and admin.py in order to implement it in your "back-end".

Hope that helps!